# How do I check whether data is there or not in more than one sql table in one script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have more than 3 sql tables.

now i'm trying to `select count(*)` from all tables but how can i do this?.

I want to know whether data is present in all tables or not

`I need to check the row count from previous business day ~15% for any table and it sends an email alert`

I tried like following please help me to complete

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendEmail_WSOTableDataAlert]
AS
BEGIN

declare @err int
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from T1) OR
NOT EXISTS (select 1 from T2)
BEGIN
set @error=1
END

//here i need to show which table is having empty data how can i do this please help

SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML +  +
            '</TABLE>' + @EmailFooter;



@error =1

then
```

send mail

```
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
    case when count(*) = 0 then 
        'No rows' 
    else 
        'Has rows'
    end 
FROM
(
   Select * from @table1
   UNION ALL
   Select * from @table2
   UNION ALL
   Select * from @table3
) t
```

**UPDATE**

This makes sure all of then have at least one row and fail if any of them does not have record

```
Select 
    case when count(*) = 0 then 
        'No rows' 
    else 
        'Has rows'
    end 
FROM
(
   Select top 1 1 found from @table1
   intersect
   Select top 1 1 found from @table2
   intersect
   Select top 1 1 found from @table3
) t
```

Comment: but how do i know which table is having 0 values?

Comment: This query returns zero only when all tables are empty; it looks like the OP is looking for a zero when **any** of the three tables is empty.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are right and have updated my answer. The OP has even edited the question. Let see what is eventually asked

Answer (score 2):

You can try multiplying the flags indicating zero counts together. If any of them is zero, the result will be zero.

```
select (case when (select count(*) from table1)=0 then 0 else 1 end
      *case when (select count(*) from table2)=0 then 0 else 1 end
      *case when (select count(*) from table3)=0 then 0 else 1 end) as no_zeros
```

If you would like to know which table has all zeros, you could transform the query as follows:

```
select (case when (select count(*) from table1)=0 then 1 else 0 end
      +case when (select count(*) from table2)=0 then 2 else 0 end
      +case when (select count(*) from table3)=0 then 4 else 0 end
      +case when (select count(*) from table4)=0 then 8 else 0 end) as no_zeros
```

Use powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and so on) as your flags. Ones `1` in the binary representation of the result will tell you which tables have no records.

Comment: Waoo! watching all your edits live and each one adds more and more in a single basic query, great answer

Answer (score 1):

(select count(*) from table1 )
union all
(select count(*) from table2 ) 
union all
(select count(*) from table3 )

And then loop through the rows of the result

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @count1 int 
select @count1 = count(*)
from table1

declare @count2 int 
select @count2 = count(*)
from table2

declare @count3 int 
select @count3 = count(*)
from table3

if (@count1 + @count2 + @count3 = 0)
    --do something
else 
    --do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EXISTS` keyword to efficiently check if there is any data in a table.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table3) 
BEGIN
   /* do something */
END
```